# Invalidate dirty rectangle with Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, invalidation, dirtyrectangle

At this class i draw simple ground for *Tic-Tae-Toe*. It consists of intercepted lines and "X" in the center of the cell.
So when User touches the cell, then `textColor` in it should be changed.

I use `invalidate(rect)` to redraw concrete cell, but in this case every cell changes it's `textColor`.

According to *Romain Guy* words, the `canvas` with whole view `Rect` comes 
for drawing. The `DisplayList` will find interceptions between drawing commands and your **dirty** `Rect`, and only those commands will be drawn. But seems, that it doesn't work so way.
[Partial invalidation in custom Android view with hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233830/partial-invalidation-in-custom-android-view-with-hardware-acceleration)

And also i found strange code change between **4.4 - 5.0** Android. So you can see, that `mCurrentDirty` disappeared from code at all.
[Android View.invalidate(Rect) different behavior between two devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915690/android-view-invalidaterect-different-behavior-between-two-devices)

P.S for **SA** this logic works correctly, and only dirty `Rect` is changed.

```
package com.eugeneshapovalov.fizmigclient

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import timber.log.Timber

class TicTacToeView : View, View.OnTouchListener {

    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    companion object {
        const val CELL_SIZE_RATIO = 1 / 3f
        const val LINE_SIZE = 2f
        const val CELL_COUNT = 3
    }

    val linePaint = Paint()
    val textPaint = Paint()
    val dirtyCell = Rect()
    var colorNumber: Int

    init {
        setOnTouchListener(this)

        colorNumber = 0
        linePaint.strokeWidth = resources.displayMetrics.density * LINE_SIZE
        textPaint.textSize = 60f
    }

    private lateinit var cells: Array<Array<Rect>>

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        initCells()
    }

    private fun initCells() {
        cells = Array(CELL_COUNT, { Array(CELL_COUNT, { Rect() }) })
        val xCell = (width * CELL_SIZE_RATIO).toInt()
        val yCell = (height * CELL_SIZE_RATIO).toInt()

        for (i in 0 until CELL_COUNT) {
            for (j in 0 until CELL_COUNT) {
                cells[i][j].left = (x + j * xCell).toInt()
                cells[i][j].top = (y + i * yCell).toInt()
                cells[i][j].right = (x + (j + 1) * xCell).toInt()
                cells[i][j].bottom = (y + (i + 1) * yCell).toInt()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        drawLines(canvas)
        drawText(canvas)
    }

    private fun drawLines(canvas: Canvas) {
        // Vertical lines
        canvas.drawLine(x + width * CELL_SIZE_RATIO, y, x + width * CELL_SIZE_RATIO, y + height, linePaint)
        canvas.drawLine(x + width * 2 * CELL_SIZE_RATIO, y, x + width * 2 * CELL_SIZE_RATIO, y + height, linePaint)
        // Horizontal lines
        canvas.drawLine(x, y + height * CELL_SIZE_RATIO, x + width, y + height * CELL_SIZE_RATIO, linePaint)
        canvas.drawLine(x, y + height * 2 * CELL_SIZE_RATIO, x + width, y + height * 2 * CELL_SIZE_RATIO, linePaint)
    }

    private fun drawText(canvas: Canvas) {
        textPaint.color = when (colorNumber % 5) {
            0 -> Color.BLACK
            1 -> Color.BLUE
            2 -> Color.RED
            3 -> Color.GRAY
            4 -> Color.YELLOW
            else -> Color.GREEN
        }

        for (i in 0 until CELL_COUNT) {
            for (j in 0 until CELL_COUNT) {
                val rect = cells[i][j]
                canvas.drawText("X", rect.exactCenterX(), rect.exactCenterY(), textPaint)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                for (i in 0 until CELL_COUNT) {
                    for (j in 0 until CELL_COUNT) {
                        val rect = cells[i][j]
                        if (rect.contains(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())) {
                            colorNumber += (j + 7)
                            Timber.d("Rect: ${rect.flattenToString()}")
                            invalidate(rect)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```